# Zebra GK420 printer internal memory

Tags: zebra-printer

Is there a way to store label format (as ZPL file) into printer's memory and recall it to print labels? I possible to set some "parametric" fields? For example I need to print a label with a standard layout (stored in printer's memory) but with some custom data for each label.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reading through the [ZPL programming manual](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/documentlibrary/manuals/en/zpl_ii_programming2.html). The methods you will be using are `^XA` (Start Format), `^DF` (Download Format), `^XF` (Recall Format), and `^FN` (Field Number).

You may need more, I have never used ZPL myself only EPL. But that should get you started.

Comment: I already found that document, but I did not read all commands. Thank you. Is there some reasons to choose EPL instead of ZPL?

Comment: EPL is the older language. I just have never worked with the newer printers that support ZPL.